# Unable to save Dictionary on ParseUser

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

Trying to save a Dictionary as a field on a ParseUser object, but its not working. Its a pretty straightforward:

```
//updateDict does implement IDictionary<string,T>

    ParseUser.CurrentUser["ItemsStatus"]= updateDict;

    ParseUser.CurrentUser.SaveAsync()
```

I've already checked to see if my dictionary has values, and I can save the user without issue if I remove the update to the dictionary field.  But if I try to add that value I just get a 400 Bad Request "Other Cause"  response from parse when I call the save task.  Any thoughts?

Comment: As long as your dictionary can be represented as a valid JSON object (contains keys in the form of strings. Values in the form of numbers, strings, or arrays and dictionaries that also conform to JSON), it should be able to be saved in any PFObject including PFUser.

Answer (score -2):

A dictionary is not a valid Parse data type.

You need to either add the elements of the dictionary to the User object individually or create a new Parse object with the elements from updateDict and create a relation to that.

Comment: At least at this point in time, you can save dictionaries and arrays into PFObjects including PFUser