# (parse.com) Can I save and fetch nested arrays and/or nested dictionaries?

Tags: parse-platform

I am designing my data models, and have a question about the limitations of what values Parse can and cannot store.

When `fetch`ing an object from Parse, will I be able to retrieve nested arrays and dictionaries, which ultimately comprise of strings and numbers?

**Example in iOS:** `@[ @[@"This is a string object"] , @[@1, @5] ]`

I am assuming that the Parse servers reject entirely custom objects e.g. `MyCustomObject : NSObject`. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dictionaries aren't allowed per this thread, but I was able to get multi-dimensional arrays to work.

[Unable to save Dictionary on ParseUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278071/unable-to-save-dictionary-on-parseuser)

Code for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
    var parseObject = PFObject(className: "myClass")
    var myNestedArray: [[AnyObject]] = [[AnyObject]]()
    myNestedArray.append(["value1", "value2"])
    parseObject["myFieldName"] = myNestedArray
    parseObject.save()
```

Obviously you'd want to finish creating the array before doing a save, but this should let you create multi-dimensional arrays in parse, eliminating the need for some joined tables.